# Understanding ROUND() function in Excel/Libre Calc

Tags: excel, rounding, openoffice-calc

I have recently discovered a weired behaviour of MS Excel as well as Libre Office Calc. When I rounded the following number directly to 1 decimal place (last column), it rounded differently than if I went to two decimal places first (2nd column) and then to one decimal place (3rd column).

```
number             ROUND(A1,2)      ROUND(A2,1)    ROUND(A1,1)
4.449331525248         4.45             4.50           4.40
```

I'm not a mathematician, but in my sense the rounding directly to one decimal place (last column) is wrong. 
Other numbers this happens to include [3.34690622103941, 4.14677866251134, 3.64939941850228, ...].

Can someone explain this phenomenon to me? Thanks!

(Please move this question to an appropriate community, if necessary)

Comment: `4.4493` rounded to 1 decimal place is `4.4` and is `4.45` rounded to 2 decimal places; `4.45` rounded to 1 decimal place is `4.5`. I don't really understand the problem. Maybe take this to [math.stackexchange.com](https://math.stackexchange.com/) if you require further explanation. Of course, you could have found the link to that community at the bottom of [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) but there it is anyway.

Comment: Your eyes keep missing a *4*. `4.4493/0.1 = 44.49` **not** `4.4493/0.1 = 44.94`.

Comment: Thanks - the mistake was obviously solely on my end! I should go to sleep instead of questioning Excel next time... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results are different because the function looks at different parts of the number to complete either two or one decimal place for its starting point.

For 2dp it looks at 4.449 which is correctly rounded to 4.45, which then correctly rounds to 1dp as 4.5. This is then an incorrect result for 1dp compared to the original source number due to the extra step and the 9.

The moral is if you need 1dp then do it in one step only 4.449 rounds to 4.4. Based on below 5 goes down, above goes up.